# Laplace Transforms: Time Domain $t$, Frequency Domain $s$, and the Functions $F(t)$ and $\mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, laplace-transform

I read the following about Laplace transforms:

> The time domain $t$ will contain all those functions $F(t)$ whose Laplace transform exists, whereas the frequency domain $s$ contains all the images $\mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \}$.

I find this explanation suspect. The time domain is $t$ -- so how does it make sense to say that it "contains" the *function* $F(t)$? I don't understand how it makes mathematical sense to say that a domain $t$ "contains" a function $F(t)$? My understanding is that $F(t)$ would be the *codomain*, whereas $t$ would be the *domain* (time domain). And I would argue the same with the frequency domain $s$ and $\mathcal \{ F(t) \}$.

Can someone please clear this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know the Laplace transform is an Operator which transforms  a function $f(t)$ into another function  $$F(s) =\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}$$

We can think of $f(t)$ as the input and $F(s)$ as the output.

Thus the domain of this operator is the set of all functions  $f(t)$ for which  $$F(s) =\mathcal{L} \{ f(t) \}$$ is convergent and the range or codomain is the set of those well defined transforms $F(s)$

Comment: But isn't your explanation of the domain and codomain different from that of the text I quoted? I agree that yours makes sense, but the explanation I quoted does not seem to make sense? It claims that the time domain $t$ "contains" the function $F(t)$. But it does not make mathematical sense to say that a domain $t$ "contains" a function?

Comment: The definition in the text leaves room for confusion. Words like time domain  or frequency domain  should have been carefully defined to avoid confusion.

Comment: Ahh, yes, It seems that the phrases "time domain" and "frequency domain" have specific mathematical definitions that I was not aware of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_domain and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_domain

Comment: Even so, with reference to the Wikipedia articles, it seems that the author has used the terminology **incorrectly**? The time domain is not $t$ as the author implies but, rather, $F(t)$; the frequency domain is not $s$ as the author implies but, rather, $\mathcal \{ F(t) \}$?

Comment: Correct. The time domain is  $\{f(t)\}$ The frequency domain is$ \{F(s)\}$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $\mathcal{L} \{ F(t) \}$. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks for your attention to details.